# Same object appears inside it in rendered mode

Tags: rendering, lighting

I was making sort of a 3D scenery but as soon as I went into rendered mode, the objects started reflecting weirdly, i got a new file and checked it again, so I saw a cube inside of the cube, it was like a reflection but i don't know what of. Please help me.[image]

Comment: Hello. This looks like a GPU problem. Update your drivers

Comment: well, I checked my drivers and tired to update them, but it showed me that they were up to date, so that hasn't fixed it.